How can get the FirstOrDefault from the DataQueryResult or convert the DataQueryResult into enumerable or list
I have a function that my code is calling, it is returning a value of type DataQueryResult<Agreement>. I need only the first result of it, how can I get the FirstOrDefault() of it or at least convert it into ToList or IEnumerable?
var _agreements = this.agreementRepository.GetAgreementsByQuery(_parameters);

The definition of the method is as below
DataQueryResult<Agreement> GetAgreementsByQuery(DataQueryParameters queryParameters)
{
   return result;
}

Any help please. The code is in C#

It depends entirely on what DataQueryResult is. If it is an Exceed.DataQueryResult then to get just the first record it looks like you would use _agreements.Data.FirstOrDefault(); If it is a proprietary class defined in your project or some other 3rd party library then you'll need to read up on how it's used.

We have not created that class but it is from Kendo.DynamicLinq namespace, but the FirstOrDefault() method is not defined in it, it seems, I am not seeing that function in its options.

Looking at the source for Kendo.DynamicLinq The DataSourceResult does have a "Data" property which is a basic IEnumerable so you don't use _agreements.FirstOrDefault(), it would be _agreements.Data.FirstOrDefault(). Though you might need to cast it to be much use, not sure why that implementation is not generic itself. To use IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault you will need a using System.Linq if you don't already have that declared.

Yes that's correct thank you so much
